# In a development environment, is it possible to bind mount package installation in docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, development-environment

We can configure the **docker files** to install packages from an already prepared list(such as **package.json, go.mod**) of dependencies.

Consider a situation where **npm is not installed in the host machine**. A developer runs a node application in a docker container in a development environment. If they want to install a package from the host machine, how'll they perform it?

I know they can modify the package.json and restart the container or get into the container and install the package there. But it'll be a hassle for developers who needs a seamless workflow.

Is there any way to bind the **npm install <package> from the host to the container**?

Comment: You could alias npm to docker exec...

Comment: Nothing you do with Docker will be simpler than `apt-get install nodejs` or a similar host package-manager command.  The Docker container by design is isolated from the host system, so the container _can't_ install packages from the host system.